# Why is my small c++ code behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: c++

```
// using structures
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct playerinfo
{
    string name;
    int level;
};

int main()
{
    playerinfo arr[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << " enter name for player " << i << endl;
        getline(cin, arr[i].name, '\n');
        cout << " and level \n";
        cin >> arr[i].level;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << "the level of player " << arr[i].name << " is " << arr[i].level << endl;
}
```

I am reading a book on c++ syntax and I am practicing. I want the code to behave such that the code asks the user to fill in the names of the players and the levels and then the code prints them all. But it is not behaving like this. when I run the code and enter the name of the player say " tom cat" then the code asks the level and I print an integer say "100", and then unexpected things start happening, the reason of which, I am unable to understand. Can you please help?
edit- few people have asked me to elaborate what "unexpected things" start happening. 
The unexpected thing is that when I type in the name of the player and the level of player 0, the next output on the screen is " enter name for player 1 and level " whereas I expect that it should only output "and level" after I enter the name of the player 1.

Comment: What "unexpected things start happening"? You ought to be more specific.

Comment: "and then unexpected things start happening" - don't you think that you should, you know, elaborate on this important bit?

Comment: This is the most charming bug report I have seen in a long time :-)

Comment: @EdS. http://timvangelder.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/sidneyharris_miracleweb.jpg

Comment: Hello everyone, I have eddited the question description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When switching from formatted input using `operator>>()`, e.g., in `cin >> arr[i].level` and unformatted input, e.g., using `std::getline()` you need to be aware of whitespace potentially waiting in the input: the formatted input of an integer stops as soon as it finds a whitespace, e.g., a newline. On the other hand, `std::getline()` will stop as soon as it find a newline! So you receive an empty line. The fix is to skip leading whitespace when switching to unformatted input, e.g.:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, arr[i].name);
```

The manipulator `std::ws` skips leading whitespace when using it with an `std::istream`.

You should also **always** verify that your inputs were successful before using them: if any input fails, the stream stops functioning and converts to `false`:

```
if (std::cin >> arr[i].level) {
    // process the data
}
else {
    // report that the input is wrong and bail out
}
```

Comment: Small typo, std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, array[i].name); should read std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, arr[i].name);

Comment: @Korchkidu: fixed the two places where I used `array` instead of `arr`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you type in the level and press enter, you are essentially inputting `100\n`. The `in >> arr[i].level` will extract the number `100` and put it in `arr[i].level`, stopping because it hit the newline, but it won't extract the newline itself. The newline is left in the input stream! The next iteration will begin, and `getline` will see that there is already some available input to read, it will attempt to read a line up to the next `\n` character. As we know, the next `\n` is the first character left in the input, so `getline` will read an empty string. From now on, your program is in a screwed up state.

A quick way to get around this is to discard characters from the input after reading the level up until and including the newline character using `ignore`:

```
cin >> arr[i].level;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This would allow the user to input `100foobar` and it would be interpreted as just `100`. That might be what you want or it might not be. If you want to accept/reject some other formats, I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Include header

```
#include <limits>
```

and before this statement

```
    getline(cin, arr[i].name, '\n');
```

insert statement

```
cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );
```

The problem is that after statement

```
cin >> arr[i].level;
```

the input buffer will keep the new line character ( '\n') after the user pressed Enter and the next getline function will read empty string before this new line character.