# why is my program skipping a step

Tags: c++, input, struct, io

this is my main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include"header.h"
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

        bool setflag = true;
    string inputcmd;

    while(setflag){
        cout << "TYPE A COMMAND" << endl;

        cin>> inputcmd;

        if (inputcmd == "make"){
                cout << "MAKING NEW PROJECT" << endl;
                get_project(cin);
            } 

        else if (inputcmd == "retrieve"){
                cout << "RETRIEVING YOUR PROJECT" << endl;
            }

        else if (inputcmd == "quit")
        { setflag = false; }

        else { cout << "invalid input please try again"; }

    }

return 0;
}
```

this is my struct code:

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    string proname;
    string prodesc;
    string protime;
}project;
```

this is my header code (where all my functions definitions are):

```
#include<iostream>
#include"project_struct.cpp"
#include<map>

project current;
map<string, project> promap;


string getFileContents(istream& file_contents){
    string line;
    getline(file_contents, line);

    return line;
} 


void get_project(istream& in){
project newproject;
    cout << "Enter your project name: ";
    newproject.proname = getFileContents(cin);

    cout << "Enter a description: ";
    newproject.prodesc = getFileContents(cin);

    cout << "How long until deadline: ";
    newproject.protime = getFileContents(cin);

    promap.insert(pair<string, project> ( newproject.proname , newproject));
    cout << endl << "You created a new project: " << newproject.proname
    << endl << "Project description: " << newproject.prodesc << endl;
```

}

my question is this, for some reason when i type make, in my cmd console input it, makes a new project but skips the name of the project, in other words it does not request the name of my project, it goes directly to ask for my project description. why is that? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Search the site for "getline skipping". I guarantee you'll find answers.

Comment: We just had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692860/why-is-my-small-c-code-behaving-unexpectedly) experiencing the same problem. Extracting the command with `>>` leaves the newline character in the input stream. When you then attempt to `getline` for the project name, it sees the newline left in the input and just extracts an empty string.

Comment: a long time ago someone recommended using cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); but that leaves me with the same problem, the only difference being i have to type in each command twice for it to register

Comment: @notamathwiz, You have to ignore the newlines left in the buffer before you call `getline` or `getline` will read that newline and stop. If there's no newline, it will wait for one. You have to use it logically.

Comment: Sounds like this would be a good C++ FAQ question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. If I put

`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

right after the `cin>>inputcmd;` in my `main()` it seems it fixes the problem.

Happy coding everyone :)